# Triggering ChartJS Point Hover from elsewhere on the page

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chartjs to generate a line graph with points for each element. Currently, hovering over a point on the graph triggers a tooltip for that data point. Is it possible to trigger this mouseover event (and the resulting tooltip) from elsewhere on the page? (More specifically, hovering over a row in a table should trigger the corresponding data point on the graph)

```
         function render_graph(input) {
            // setup block
            const data = {
                datasets: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    parsing: {
                        yAxisKey: 'Average Pace',
                        xAxisKey: 'Date',
                    },
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    radius: 3,
                    data: arr,
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    label: "Pace",
                }]
            }

            // config block
            const config = {
                data,
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                unit: 'year'
                            }
                        },
                        y: {
                            suggestedMin: 360,
                            suggestedMax: 900,
                            ticks: {
                                stepSize: 30,
                                padding: 2,
                                callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                                    minutes = Math.floor(value / 60);
                                    seconds = value % 60;
                                    if (seconds == 0) {
                                        seconds = "00";
                                    }
                                    x = minutes + ':' + seconds;

                                    return x;
                                }
                            },                   
                        }
                    },
                }
            };

            // render / init block
            const myChart = new Chart(
                document.getElementById('myChart'),
                config
            );
            return myChart;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setActiveElements` tooltip/chart API. Here is a snippet code to show how it works.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'Fabruary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'user 1 online',
            data: [50, 35, 45, 47, 0, 3, 27],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(40, 139, 170, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(40, 139, 170)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'yellow',
            pointHoverRadius: 20
        }]
    }
});
document.getElementById('chart').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (myChart.getActiveElements().length > 0) {
    myChart.setActiveElements([]);
  } else {
    myChart.setActiveElements([
      {
        datasetIndex: 0,
        index: 1,
      }, {
        datasetIndex: 0,
        index: 3,
      }
    ]);
  }
  myChart.update();
});
document.getElementById('tooltip').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const tooltip = myChart.tooltip;  
  if (tooltip.getActiveElements().length > 0) {
    tooltip.setActiveElements([], {x: 0, y: 0});
  } else {
    const chartArea = myChart.chartArea;
    tooltip.setActiveElements([
      {
        datasetIndex: 0,
        index: 1
      }
    ],
    {
      x: (chartArea.left + chartArea.right) / 2,
      y: (chartArea.top + chartArea.bottom) / 2,
    });
  }
  myChart.update();
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
    <button id="chart">Chart active element</button>
    <button id="tooltip">Tooltip active element</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#setactiveelements-activeelements

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32496701)

Comment: I see. Let me take time to provide a full example instead of only the link